# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to OOP and trying to recall a function from a parent class in Facebook WP plugin, I get the error from the file of the parent class

my code is:

```
class check_fb extends Wdfb_Model {
function __construct() {
            Wdfb_Model::get_wp_user_from_fb();
    }
}

//REST OF THE CODE
```

here is the code for the class http://codepad.org/d7MtD9i7 knowing that it is a class within a WP facebook plugin and works well within that plugin

generally what I am trying to do is define the property `$this->fb->api('/me');` in the my class to get the user FB information, since I can't declare the class FACEBOOK which is already declared from the plugin.

Comment: try calling `parent::__construct();` as the first statement of your class's constructor. that will set the necessary credentials i guess.

Comment: @Jeffrey I updated the code as follows class check_fb extends Wdfb_Model {
 function parent::__construct() {
    Wdfb_Model::get_wp_user_from_fb();
 }
}
 now I am getting this error..PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting '('

Answer (score 0):

Change "Wdfb_model::" to "$this->":

```
$this->get_wp_user_from_fb();
```

Comment: I did this but still getting the same error  PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in class_wdfb_model.php on line  232, the code for this page is right here http://codepad.org/d7MtD9i7, thank you